# Reading a device from kernel interrupt

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I'm aiming to have a kernel module that reads a device (ADC) at every T seconds.
I already have a working module that calls a interrupt each T seconds and I also have another module that reads a user space file (the ADC, for instance), which I got from [this example](http://www.howtoforge.com/reading-files-from-the-linux-kernel-space-module-driver-fedora-14). **Both work fine separately**.

The problem is that when I try to open and read any file from my interrupt routine the module crashes

```
[   80.636932] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
```

My code is something like this:

```
static irqreturn_t timer_irq_handler(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    uint16_t value;

    // reset the timer interrupt status
    omap_dm_timer_write_status(timer_ptr, OMAP_TIMER_INT_OVERFLOW);
    omap_dm_timer_read_status(timer_ptr);

    omap_dm_timer_set_load(timer_ptr, 1, 0xFFFFFFFF - (time * gt_rate);

    value = read_channel();

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

uint16_t read_channel()
{
    // Create variables
    struct file *f;
    char buf[128];
    mm_segment_t fs;
    int i;
    // Init the buffer with 0
    for(i=0;i \< 128;i++)
        buf[i] = 0;

    f = filp_open(device, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if(f == NULL)
        printk(KERN_ALERT "filp_open error!!.\n");
    else{
        // Get current segment descriptor
        fs = get_fs();
        // Set segment descriptor associated to kernel space
        set_fs(get_ds());
        // Read the file
        f->f_op->read(f, buf, 128, &f->f_pos);
        // Restore segment descriptor
        set_fs(fs);
        // See what we read from file
        printk(KERN_INFO "buf:%s\n",buf);
    }
    filp_close(f,NULL);
    return 0;
}

static int __init mq7_driver_init(void)
{
    int ret = 0;
    struct clk *gt_fclk;

    timer_ptr = omap_dm_timer_request();
    if(timer_ptr == NULL){
        printk("No more gp timers available, bailing out\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // set the clock source to system clock
    omap_dm_timer_set_source(timer_ptr, OMAP_TIMER_SRC_SYS_CLK);

    // set prescalar to 1:1
    omap_dm_timer_set_prescaler(timer_ptr, 0);

    // figure out what IRQ our timer triggers
    timer_irq = omap_dm_timer_get_irq(timer_ptr);

    // install our IRQ handler for our timer
    ret = request_irq(timer_irq, timer_irq_handler, IRQF_DISABLED | IRQF_TIMER , "mq7_driver", timer_irq_handler);
    if(ret){
    printk("mq7_driver: request_irq failed (on irq %d), bailing out\n", timer_irq);
    return ret;
    }

    // get clock rate in Hz
    gt_fclk = omap_dm_timer_get_fclk(timer_ptr);
    gt_rate = clk_get_rate(gt_fclk);

    // set preload, and autoreload
    // we set it to the clock rate in order to get 1 overflow every 3 seconds
    omap_dm_timer_set_load(timer_ptr, 1, 0xFFFFFFFF - (5 * gt_rate)); // dobro do tempo

    // setup timer to trigger our IRQ on the overflow event
    omap_dm_timer_set_int_enable(timer_ptr, OMAP_TIMER_INT_OVERFLOW);

    // start the timer!
    omap_dm_timer_start(timer_ptr);

    // get acess to gpio
    ret = gpio_request(gpio, "mq7_driver sck"); 
    if (ret) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "gpio_request %d failed\n",gpio);
        gpio_free(gpio);
        return -1;
    }
    gpio_direction_output(gpio, 0);

    // Print adc number into address string
    sprintf(device,"/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon0/device/in%d_input",adc);

    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with reading a file **from a interrupt routine**?

*P.S.: It's running on a Overo (ARM), the distro is Poky and kernel version is 3.5.7.*

Comment: This is fundamentally the wrong way to do things.  If you want to do the reading in-kernel for purposes of precise timing, then you should merge this into the actual ADC driver, and not try to re-use its userspace interface from within a kernel ISR.  You could for example have the adc driver collect data periodically and buffer it for userspace to read.  Or, if timing is not critical, then you should do the whole thing from userspace.

Comment: 99.999% of the time, if you need to read a file from the kernel, you're doing something very, very wrong. The rare times you do need to, there are existing kernel interfaces for it (e.g. reading firmware files) and even then, the kernel doesn't actually read the files directly.

Comment: I see that's not the better way to go, I'll try some better approach, maybe do it all in user space. But, in any case, why does it not work? Since reading a file from a module worked I also expected it to work from a irq_handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the answer of @VivekS in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391224/polling-a-loop-device-through-a-kernel-module) I took a look at Linux Device Drivers, chapter 10, which states:

> A handler can't transfer data to or from user space, because it
>   doesn't execute in the context of a process. Handlers also cannot do
>   anything that would sleep, such as calling wait_event, allocating
>   memory with anything other than GFP_ATOMIC, or locking a semaphore.
>   Finally, handlers cannot call schedule.

Comment: Nice to see that you've not only accepted the issue with this approach, but gone a step further and found a nice reference on why it is unworkable.